My DTM File is somewhat altered or missing when I import it into QGIS
What is happening to this DTM? I'm trying to delineate using this DTM but this is what I get when I import it unto QGIS. This is a 1 m x 1 m DTM of the Cebu province in the Philippines.
The first image is an .OVR file requested from a reliable source here in the Philippines. And the 2nd image is a .TIF file given to me by my professor. Basically the 2nd image was what I'm expecting to get. But then the result of the 1st image was not a good sight. I couldn't delineate the 1st image, so I gave up and ended up here.



it would really help if you would explain (or show a screenshot) of what you were expecting.

just posted another image. I just want to know why the 1st image is different than the 2nd image.

What is .OVR file? The only .ovr that I know is used by GDAL for storing the external overviews, and those files are not supposed to be used stand-alone but together with the full resolution image. Maybe your .OVR is something else.

I think they sent you the wrong file. I agree with user30184, an ovr file are the overviews for another raster, like a tif.

Yes, the OVR is a reduced resolution overview file, get your reliable source to send you the data file (most likely to be a .tif file, but can be other format/file extension).

Thank you guys. Already emailed them.
